# update my state with null after dispatch an action in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I dispatch an action to a reducer, other reducers are affected and their states changed

mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps functions:

```
    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return { modalVisible: state.assignSchema.modalVisible };
    };
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        onModalShow: data => {
          dispatch({
            type: 'SHOW',
            payload: data,
          });
        },
        onModalHide: () => {
          dispatch({ type: 'HIDE' });
        },
      };
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AssignToSchema);
```

reducer:

```
function assignSchemaReducer(state, action) {
  state = {
    modalVisible: 'Initial',
    selectedDomId: undefined,
  };
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW':
      switch (action.payload.type) {
        case 'link':
          return {
            ...state,
            modalVisible: 'SHOW',
            // selectedTarget: action.key.anchorTagId,
            // textTagId: action.key.textTagId,
            // schemaId: action.key.current_schema_id,
          };
        case 'node':
          return {
            ...state,
            modalVisible: 'SHOW',
            selectedDomElementId: action.key.ElementId,
          };
        case 'sc':
          return {
            ...state,
            modalVisible: 'SHOW',
            selectedDomElementId: action.key.ElementId,
          };
      }

    case 'HIDE':
      return {
        ...state,
        modalVisible: 'HIDE',
        selectedDomId: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default assignSchemaReducer;
```

after dispatch `SHOW` action to `assignSchemaReducer` other reducers are affected and their states changed. also I usign combine reducer for handle multiple reducers

[image: change states after dispatch SHOW action]

[UPDATE] other reducers
schemaFormReducer:

```
function schemaFormReducer(state, action) {
  state = {
    modalVisible: 'Initial',
    actionType: null,
  };
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW':
      return {
        ...state,
        modalVisible: 'SHOW',
        actionType: action.type,
      };
    case 'HIDE':
      return {
        ...state,
        modalVisible: 'HIDE',
        actionType: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default schemaFormReducer;
```

treeSelectReducer:

```
const treeSelectReducer = (state, action) => {
  state = {
    modalVisible: 'Initial',
    selectedSchemaId: undefined,
  };
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SCHEMA_ID': {
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedSchemaId: action.payload,
      };
    }
    case 'UNSET_SCHEMA_ID': {
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedSchemaId: null,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default treeSelectReducer;
```

history reducer:

```
function historyReducer(state, action) {
  state = {
    modalVisible: "Initial",
    selectedNodeId: null,
    tagCode: null
  };
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SHOW":
      return {
        ...state,
        modalVisible: "SHOW",
        selectedNodeId: action.key,
        unitMeasureSymbol: action.unitMeasureSymbol,
        tagCode: action.tagCode
      };
    case "HIDE":
      return {
        ...state,
        modalVisible: "HIDE",
        selectedNodeId: null
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default historyReducer;
```

thanks...

Comment: `SHOW`/`HIDE` are pretty generic action types, are other reducers listening for these same types but missing "payloads"? You seem to also have a lot of duplicated state (maybe that is because of "cross-talk") in your reducers, or you *actually* have duplicated data in state. Can you post up your other reducer code?

Comment: a good pattern in Redux is to make "all actions distinct". it's clear for you as the coder what is happening that way, allowing you to easily separate stuff and fire the right action

Answer (score 0):

Try to export the action to a function (could be another file called `actions.js`).

For example:

```
// action.js file
const hideAction = (data) => {
     return {
        type: 'SHOW',
        payload: data,
      }
};

// reducer.js file
import {hideAction} from './action.js';
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  hideAction
};

// tagetFile.js
   render(){
     const {hideAction} = this.props;
     const data = {a:1, b:2};
     hideAction(data);
   }
```